# How do I connect a Drupal content type to CiviMail? CiviRules?

Tags: civimail, drupal, civirules

I'm still getting my head around CiviCRM, and also only have admin access (but not sftp) so if I need to get into the code I'll have to ask our external support team.

I want to be able to take the HTML from a certain type of content when posted on our Drupal 7 site (Media Release) and automatically send it to a CiviCRM Mailing List group.

CiviRules out of the box only allows CiviCRM events as triggers; is there a robust way to link it to Drupal events? Is it only possible through code rather than a UI option somewhere?

Addendum: I've started playing with com.pogstone.contenttokens to get drupal content across, but am not sure how to get the full version rather than a teaser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We built a [solution](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_views_token) that uses Drupal Views and a you can then use a token to deliver the content of that view in to a CiviMail. That may be useful to you or it may at least put your 'external support team' on to the job. There was a discussion on the old forum about this [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=31956.0)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand you question. What is the reason for using Drupal events rather than CiviCRM events? I would imagine if you want to link Drupal events to CiviCRM you would need some coding.

Comment: Sorry, I meant event as in trigger - a thing to start a process.